# Postgres perform regex query on jsonb field

Tags: sql, postgresql, peewee

I have a column in my Postgres database that stores jsonb type values. Some of these values are raw strings (not a list or dictionary). I want to be able to perform a regex search on this column, such as

```
select * from database where jsonb_column::text ~ regex_expression.
```

The issue is that for values that are already strings, converting from jsonb to text adds additional escaped double quotes at the beginning and end of the value. I don't want these included in the regex query. I understand why Postgres does this, but if, say we assume all values stored in the jsonb field were jsonb strings, is there a work around? I know you can use ->> to get a value out of a jsonb dictionary, but can't figure out a solution for just jsonb strings on their own.

Once I figure out how to make this query in normal Postgres, I want to translate it into Peewee. However, any and all help with even just the initial query would be appreciated!

Comment: You could use a JSON /PATH expression, e.g. `where jsonb_column @@ '$.* like_regexp ...'` but without more details it's a bit hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the json to text. Here is an example:

```
class Reg(Model):
    key = CharField()
    data = BinaryJSONField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

for i in range(10):
    Reg.create(key='k%s' % i, data={'k%s' % i: 'v%s' % i})

# Find the row that contains the json string "k1": "v1".
expr = Reg.data.cast('text').regexp('"k1": "v1"')
query = Reg.select().where(expr)
for row in query:
    print(row.key, row.data)
```

Prints

```
k1 {'k1': 'v1'}
```

Comment: My question is more surrounding a feature of Postgres for strings that are in json columns. When casting a json type string to TEXT, it adds an additional set of escaped double quotes around this string. However, I don't want these to be present.  For example, the string 'hello' stored as a json string will be 5 characters in length. However when casting the column to text (.cast('text)), it creates a TEXT-type string 7 characters in length that is '\"hello\"'.

Erwin has a solution that I also found, using ```#>> '{}'```, but I don't know how to represent this in peewee?

Answer (score -1):

To extract a plain string (string primitive without key name) from a JSON value (`json` or `jsonb`), you can extract the "empty path" like:

```
SELECT jsonb '"my string"' #>> '{}';
```

This also works for me (with `jsonb` but not with `json`), but it's more of a hack:

```
SELECT jsonb '"my string"' ->> 0
```

So:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (jsonb_column #>> '{}') ~ 'my regex here';
```